# How can the Therns change their physical bodies?

Tags: john-carter, edgar-rice-burroughs, barsoom

I have read that the Therns are like any normal Martian, but how can they change their physical bodies? Is it like a disguise?

Answer (score 2):

In the book, the Therns do not have any form of shapeshifting powers (they live hidden from the rest of the world, at the end of the Ys river, posing as gods).

In the movie, this appears to be a function of their medallions and bracelets rather than a natural ability: While changing appearance, the Therns eyes glow with a pale blue light also present in all other applications of the Ninth ray shown in the movie (as a weapon or powering their strange pyramidal structure).